# Problem with changing nested dict values in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a problem trying to change values in a nested dictionary:

```
dictionary = {"2000": {"1.1.1.": 1, "1.2.3.": 5, "1.2.1.": 1}, "2001": {"1.2.3.": 5, "1.1.4.5.": 1}, "2002": {"1.1.1.": 1, "1.2.3.": 10}, "2003": {"1.1.1.": 5, "1.2.3.4.5.6.": 10}}
hierarchies = {"1.1.1.", "1.2.3."}

peryear_values = dict.fromkeys(list(sorted(dictionary.keys())), 0) 
h_values = dict.fromkeys(list(hierarchies), peryear_values)  
for hierarchy in hierarchies:
    for year, values in sorted(dictionary.items()):
        if hierarchy in values.keys():
            print("\nThe hierarchy: ", hierarchy)
            print("In year: ", year)
            print("The value: ", values[hierarchy])
            h_values[hierarchy][year] = values[hierarchy]
print(h_values)
```

The desired output:

```
{"1.1.1.": {"2000": 1, "2001": 0, "2002": 1, "2003": 5}, "1.2.3": {"2000": 5, "2001": 5, "2002": 10, "2003": 0}}
```

The output that I get:

```
{'1.1.1.': {'2000': 5, '2001': 5, '2002': 10, '2003': 5}, '1.2.3.': {'2000': 5, '2001': 5, '2002': 10, '2003': 5}}
```

It seems that for each iteration the value of both "hierarchy" keys changes, instead of respecting the change in the specific one.
Is there something I'm doing wrong?

I'm running python 3.9.7 and conda 4.12.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  There is only one `peryear_values` dict in your program.  When you create `h_values`, you are just storing multiple references to that one dictionary.  You can't use `dict.fromkeys` for this.  You'll have to use a loop and use `peryear_values.copy()`.

```
h_values = dict( (h, peryear_values.copy()) for h in hierarchies )
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm sorry I can't give you a positive vote, I'm new to the platform